# jquery accessing/changing value attribute of an element

Tags: jquery, attributes

how to deal with value attribute of any element (hidden input in my case)

i have tried with two styles

```
alert($("#projectManager").attr("value"));

and 

alert($("#projectManager").val());
```

but it returns 'undefined'.

any help?

Comment: is that within a $(document).ready block? Do elements with those IDs exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify id="projectManager" on the input field. a 'name' attribute is not enough for this selector. And .val() is the way to go to get a field value.

Comment: thank you, i just missed it i have given name instead of id.
BTW how did u know i have used name? :-)

Comment: Because that's the required attribute for a form element - otherwise you won't get it on the server when submitted :)